# How to prettify ASCII-art guitar tablature in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build an interactive website that users can open a file (the file is stored in the same folders as the website files, just to be clear), and this file will display guitar tablature on the screen in a "pretty" format. I am just learning in my web design journey, and the only things I've dabbled with are HTML and CSS. I'm starting a JavaScript course in a few weeks, and I know that's where the interactivity part of it will come in, but for now I'm satisfied with just making it display the tablature.

The program I use for creating the tablature (TablEdit) can export tablature as a MIDI (.mid), an ASCII, an RTF, an HTML, an ABC, or a Lilypond, or of course it's own proprietary file type, the TEF.

I thought I had found some hope when I realized that it exports in HTML, but it uses the `<pre>` tag to force the browser to display the tablature just as it's typed into the HTML file, which is a bunch of dashes and numbers.

Here's the HTML exported directly from TablEdit - meaning I haven't done anything to it myself...and yes, I know this is banjo tablature instead of guitar.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<TITLE>noplace.tef</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica, Arial">
<CENTER>
<FONT SIZE="+2">noplace.tef</FONT>
<BR><FONT SIZE="+1"></FONT>
</CENTER>
<P ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT SIZE="-1">TablEdited by </FONT></P>
<P></FONT><PRE>
4/4 

 |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        
|----0---------------------------|0-------0-----------------------|----0-----------0---------------|
|--------------------------------|----------------1-----------1---|--------------------------------|
|----0---------------------------|0-----------------------3-------|--------3-------0---------------|
|--------0-------3-------4-------|--------------------------------|------------------------3-------|
|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|0-------------------------------|
 
 |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        
|0-----------0---------------0---|------------0-------------------|0-------0-----------------------|
|--------1h3---------1-----------|1-------1-----------1-----------|----------------1-----------1---|
|0-----------------------3-------|------------------------3-------|0-----------------------3-------|
|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|----------------0---------------|------------0-------------------|--------------------------------|
 
 |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        
|----0-----------0---------------|0-----------0-----------0-------|3-------3p2-----0---------------|
|--------------------------------|--------1h3---------3-----------|--------------------1-----------|
|--------3-------0---------------|0-------------------------------|------------------------3-------|
|------------------------3-------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|0-------------------------------|----------------0-----------0---|--------0-----------------------|
 
 |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        
|0-------0-----------------------|----0-----------0---------------|0-----------0---------------0---|
|----------------1-----------1---|--------------------------------|--------1h3---------1-----------|
|0-----------------------3-------|--------3-------0---------------|0-----------------------3-------|
|--------------------------------|------------------------3-------|--------------------------------|
|--------------------------------|0-------------------------------|----------------0---------------|
 
 |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        
|------------0-------------------|----0-----------0-----------0---|--------0-------0-------0-------|
|1-------1-----------1-----------|1h3---------3-----------1h3-----|----3---------------------------|
|------------------------3-------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|------------0-------------------|--------0-----------------------|0-----------0-----------0-------|
 
 |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        |       |       |       |        
|0-------0-------3-------2-------|0-----------0-------------------|0---------------0-----------0---|
|--------------------------------|----1---------------------------|--------------------------------|
|--------------------------------|--------3-------2---0-----------|0-----------------------0-------|
|--------------------------------|------------------------3-------|--------------------------------|
|--------0-------0-------0-------|--------------------------------|--------0-----------0-----------|
 
</PRE>

</BR>
Tablature Legend</BR>
----------------</BR>
h - hammer-on</BR>
p - pull-off</BR>
<P>
<FONT SIZE="-2">
Created with <A HREF="https://tabledit.com/">TablEdit, Tablature Editor</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

My goal is to, instead of it looking like it does above, I want the "strings" to be like a background image or something, and each "note" to be a colored circle with the number in the middle. I may not be advanced enough in my journey for this though.

I did style a copy of the same HTML code using an external CSS sheet, but it didn't really get me anywhere near where I was trying to go, since when I remove the  tag from the HTML, it makes a total mess.

Comment: ABC is designed to be rendered in the browser. it's what music.stackexchange.com use. So look into using abcjs

Comment: Sorry! I don't know how to properly edit my post to completely isolate the code! Seems I made a mistake while posting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use the ABC format that your program supports exporting, and use the popular JavaScript library abcjs to render it on your webpages.

```js
ABCJS.renderAbc("music", $("#music").text(), {
  tablature: [
    { instrument: "guitar" }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/abcjs/6.2.2/abcjs-basic-min.js" integrity="sha512-KXKtG2UKjAKEEwwKKNioYwVHGm/gH0ZmME+ePGFwbjs4Banx6+xJVtDpC2A2QM9nGtamOP4tqEYfxloLjq3XcA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="music">
X: 1
T: Cooley's
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: Emin
|:D2|"Em"EBBA B2 EB|\
    ~B2 AB dBAG|\
    "D"FDAD BDAD|\
    FDAD dAFD|
"Em"EBBA B2 EB|\
    B2 AB defg|\
    "D"afe^c dBAF|\
    "Em"DEFD E2:|
|:gf|"Em"eB B2 efge|\
    eB B2 gedB|\
    "D"A2 FA DAFA|\
    A2 FA defg|
"Em"eB B2 eBgB|\
    eB B2 defg|\
    "D"afe^c dBAF|\
    "Em"DEFD E2:|
</div>
```

[The tablature configuration reference](https://paulrosen.github.io/abcjs/visual/tablature.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with JavaScript yet, so how "familiar" should I get before I dive into this?

Comment: @hjlemon02 not at all. The best way to learn a new technology is by using it, and googling every single question or wall you come up against. I think this is a good starting point, especially since abcjs is so well-documented and well-known.